# Kali Linux doesn't recognize Nvidia GT220

Tags: kali-linux, nvidia

I have an Nvidia GT220 graphic card that kali doesn't detect it. I refer to the following links but problem has not been resolved.

[image]

When I install driver and reboot the machine, linux does not boot. And I got the following error:

[image]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CnLxyxzXuD8

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fKd1UvUPOjY

Note: I've installed kali dual boot.

Comment: 1) Does Windows detect the card? 2) Which Linux driver is in use now? 3) Please update with `update-pciids` then run `lspci | grep -i --color 'vga\|3d\|2d'` and `nvidia-smi` then click [edit] and update your question with this useful information. 4) Have you tried https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/81761/en-us  ? Please do NOT reply with [Add Comment] because comments pile up and scroll off the page; your responses are most important, so please put them in the Question where all can see them.

Comment: "Which Linux driver is in use now?" How can I know that?

Comment: Run `lshw -c video` , and look for the line with "configuration". The loaded driver is prefixed with "driver=". Kaii is a distro for experts who are presumed to know these very basic tools. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me

Comment: I edited the post.

Comment: I would suggest you wipe off Kali and use Debian or Ubuntu to set up your dualboot, and get the NVidia card working in that OS. Once you know you can make the card work on a normal operating system, then you can consider if it is worth the effort to try making it work in Kali. https://docs.kali.org/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux

Comment: Your lspci clearly shows that the nvidia card was detected. I second the suggestion by 0xSheepdog to read the kali page on if you should be using it. Basically, to me, if you get stuck with a simple graphics issue, you shouldn't be using kali.